# in html form tag where does uploaded image stored before submit

Tags: html

I'm creating a webpage to test some functionality.

I used the `<input type="file">` to ask for user upload a file. I was wondering where does the file store and in what format after loading the file but before user click submit button? Does it temporarily copy the entire file?

Is there a method in **html 5** to preview the image if I uploaded an image without the help of JS?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> where does the file store and in what format after loading the file but before user click submit button?"

That's a browser implementation detail. There's no standard for it and it's entirely possible the browser does nothing with the file until the form is submitted or the file is accessed with JS.

> Is there a method in html 5 to preview the image if I uploaded an image without the help of JS?

No.